# How is this step done? $\left|\frac{i\overline{z}}{2} -\frac i2\right|=\frac{|z-1|}{2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Absolutely everything makes sense other than what is in red. How is this step completed?

> Let us show that if $f(z)=\dfrac{i\overline{z}}{2}$ in the open disk $|z|\lt 1$, then$$\lim \limits_{z\to1}f(z)=\frac i2.$$
>   That the point $1$ being on the boundary of the domain of $f$. Observe that when $z$ is in the disk $|z|\lt 1,$
>
> $$\left|f(z)-\frac i2\right|=\color{red}{\left|\frac{i\overline{z}}{2} -\frac i2\right|=\frac{|z-1|}{2}}.$$
>
> Hence for any such $z$ and each positive number $\epsilon$,
>
> $$\left|f(z) -\frac i2\right|\lt \epsilon$$ whenever $$0\lt |z-1| \lt 2\epsilon.$$

My attempt to resolve:

$$i\overline{z} - i=i(a-bi)-i=ai+b-i=(a-1)i+b\ne (a+bi-1)$$

Comment: $|a \cdot b| = |a|\cdot |b|$.

Comment: @Kaster Is that just dealing with the denominator leaving the absolute value? That part was fine, it was numerator I didn't understand

Comment: factor the numerator as $|i(\overline{z} - 1)|$

Comment: @OceansBleed: I hope you don't mind, I edited your post to make it clearer which parts are written by you, and which parts come from a resource you are reading. Feel free to rollback if you prefer it the way you had it.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese The edit is appreciated. It looks much nicer. Thanks for the edit and the clear and concise answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the intermediate steps are $$\left|\frac{i\bar{z}}{2} - \frac{i}{2}\right| = |i|\left|\frac{\bar{z}}{2} - \frac{1}{2}\right| = 1\frac{|\bar{z} - 1|}{2} = \frac{1}{2}\left|\overline{z - 1}\right| = \frac{1}{2}|z - 1|$$

where the last equality follows from the fact that $|\bar{a}| = |a|$ for all $a \in \mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 1):

If $z$ is a complex number, we have $z=x+iy~,~x,y\in\Bbb{R}$ and $\bar{z}=x-iy$

Note that,

$$|z|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}~\textrm{and}~|\bar{z}|=\sqrt{x^2+(-y)^2}=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\\ \implies |z|=|\bar{z}|$$

Now, following Kaster's comment,

$$\left|\frac{i\bar{z}}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\right|=\frac{1}{2}|\bar{z}-1|=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}=\frac{1}{2}|(x-1)+iy|=\frac{1}{2}|\bar{z}-1|$$

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$\left \vert i \overline{z} - i \right \vert = \left \vert i \right \vert \left \vert \overline{z}-1 \right \vert = \left \vert \overline{z}-1\right \vert = \left \vert \overline {z-1}\right \vert = \left \vert {z-1}\right \vert$$